# webpack doesn't generate bundle.js?

Tags: node.js, webpack

I don't really understand why but the dist folder is always empty and I get no errors

It says that everything was emitted, but in fact there is nothing in the destination folder?

```
                         Asset       Size  Chunks                         Chunk Names
bundle.c0940e804d5eef0a0480.js    129 KiB       0  [emitted] [immutable]  main
                   favicon.ico   14.9 KiB          [emitted]
                    index.html  405 bytes          [emitted]
```

My webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path')
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

var isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
var isDev = !isProd

module.exports = {
  entry: './app.jsx',
  mode: 'development',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname + 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.[hash].js',
  },
  devtool: isDev ? 'source-map' : false,
  plugins: [
    new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'index.html',
      favicon: 'public/favicon.ico'
    }),
  ], 
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          cacheDirectory: true,
          presets: ['react', 'es2015']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader'
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

script: `"build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --mode production"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
```

now it works